# How to convert a list of lists, containing lists, into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have currently been trying to convert a list of lists of lists into a dataframe. Please see the example below:

```
data = [[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
[[4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6]],
[[7], [8], [9]]]
```

and I would like to have a result like this

```
1        2        3        
1        2        3        
1        2        3        
4        5        6
4        5        6
7        8        9
```

Could anyone please give me a suggestion or solution? or is there any package being able to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `column_stack`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack(data).T)

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
3  4  5  6
4  4  5  6
5  7  8  9
```